# Deleting an item from a Mongo array using Mongoid and Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

I have an embedded document that that has an array of contributors.  Contributors is an array of user ID's of people who have contributed to the document.

```
field :contributors, type: Array, :default => []
```

Here's an example item from the console:

```
#<Item _id: 5249d5bd06387b91a600000f, name: "Collapse", contributors: ["51db6d58bd02861e96000004", "51db6d58bd02861e96000004"], count: 2>
```

I want to be able to remove the first matching contributor in an item from the array, but every time I try and test just to see if the user's id is present in contributors array, it returns false when clearly it is there.

Here's an example:

```
contributors.include?("51db6d58bd02861e96000004")
 => false
```

How do i work with array values from Mongoid? Why is this returning false?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

contributor is an Array of Strings or ObjectIds?

Try instead:

`contributors.include?( Moped::BSON::ObjectId.from_string "51db6d58bd02861e96000004")`

I don't really know your whole application. but have you considered this approach?

```
class Item
 has_and_belongs_to_many :users, foreign_key: :contributors
end
```

Comment: Yes, I needed to add the Moped::BSON::ObjectId.  Thank you for that!